# How to use FormHelper and FluentValidation in .netcore 6 razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-6.0

I am moving away from mvc to razor pages but can't seem to find my way around with the validation using fluent validator and FormHelper.

Normally with the mvc pattern

```
[FormValidator]
Public async Task<IActionResult> submitFormAction()
{
    // do something 
    return View();
}
```

With Razor page

```
 public class AddModel : PageModel
 {
     public void OnGet()
     {

     }
 
     // 'FormValidator' cannot be applied to razor page handler
     // method it may be applied to either Razor page model or
     // applied globally
     [FormValidator]
     public async Task OnPostAsync()
     {
         
     }
 }
```

Comment: You have a controller (IActionResult).  See blue notes on following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-controller

Comment: @jdweng the question is how can I add `[FormValidator]` to razor page OnPost

Comment: Is the ``[FormValidator]`` custom made?

Comment: No, it's a [nuget package](https://github.com/sinanbozkus/FormHelper) that helps you bring server side validation to client side

Comment: What is the actual problem? After you add the ``[FormValidator]`` to your ``OnPost`` action what happens..

Comment: @VeronicaAsuquo : The question is how to use Razor with a Controller.

Comment: @jdweng apparently it doesn't work that way with razor pages

Comment: @jdweng please explain more on what you mean by Razor with a controller

Comment: Maybe show the actual (stripped version) of your Razor code instead of only the MVC version. It's a bit confusing now I guess

Comment: IActionResult is body of a Request/Response when you use a controller.  You said you were moving to Razor and link I provided talks about using Razor with a controller.

Comment: This issue is the FormValidator attribute is only made for MVC. It uses the ActionFilterAttribute, but Razor Pages uses PageFilters (https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/filters). You would have to copy this code (https://github.com/sinanbozkus/FormHelper/blob/76a1c97c3733e3d17ec389d617b0e324123ecc73/src/FormHelper/Attributes/FormValidator.cs#L17) and write it into a class that implements IPageFilterAsync. (OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync method should equal OnActionExecutionAsync method)

Comment: It looks like this is what you need: https://github.com/sinanbozkus/FormHelper/issues/12. Then you would use   services.RazorPages(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new FormValidatorRazor());
    });

Comment: @thewallrus i already did something similar by extending the **FormValidator** attribute to  a filter but i wasn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else facing the same issue.

The problem is with `FluentValidation`, in previous version .netcore you could register the `FluentValidation` service by simply

```
service.AddFluentValidation(config => config.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<StartUp>());
```

with the code above .netcore uses reflection to register all the classes in `StartUp.cs` assembly that inherits `AbstractValidator<T>`

but with the .netcore 6, i had to still use the code above but replaced the `Startup` with `Program` as .netcore 6 doesn't make use of `StartUp.cs` and still had to implicitly register the validation services

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IValidator<SomeClass>, SomeClassValidator>();
```

This works for me but i have a feeling it could be simplified more because if am working on a large app and i have upto 20 validators my `Program.cs` won't be maintainable

PS: the `[FormValidator]` on the action method is obsolete as using the `asp-FormHelper="true"` tag helper along is okay

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the following package for integrating FluentValidation into an ASP.NET Core application?

I believe this will include the necessary extension method(s) to allow you to register FluentValidation as the service you want to leverage for performing validation.

https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation.AspNetCore#aspnet-core-integration-for-fluentvalidation

Comment: I am already familiar with using fluent validation and formhelper on MVC but not on razor pages, fluent validation works alright on my razor pages but using it with formhelper, Is the Question

Comment: Unfortunately, the .AspNetCore extension is no longer being recommended by the project creator for various reasons, one of which is it doesn't support asynchronous rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this git Issues :

> ASP.NET Core Razor Pages - validator for PageModel not invoked, even though validators for properties are invoked properly #887

https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/887

Comment: thanks but i had already read through on the link you provided before posting  issue